# How can we be sure a proof technique can actually prove something?

Tags: solution-verification, proof-writing

Induction is a great tool used to prove some propositions. However it seems that these propositions require some level of simplicity for us to be able prove them using only induction. If we wanted, for example, to prove Fermat's last theorem using induction on the exponential, I think we would have a very difficult time.

Regardless of that, if $\phi$ (n) is the statement:$n > 2$  $\land$  $x^n + y^n = z^n$ has no natural solutions. Since Fermat's last theorem is now proved the statement: $\phi (0)$ $ \land $ $\forall x(\phi(x) \implies \phi(x+1))$ is trivially true. (trivially in the sense that it follows directly from Wile's proof of Fermat's last theorem). Then, using in the Induction Scheme, we can conclude that $\forall x \phi (x)$

So, the induction scheme over our statement is provable. But i doubt that anyone would ever be capable of proving Fermat's last theorem using only induction.

Is there a formalization of the concept of "proof technique"? Are there current theories which could, theoretically, prove that if a computer is programmed to only search for proofs using induction, it would never be capable of proving Fermat's last theorem?

Apologies if this question is too vague.

Comment: See "reverse mathematics" or "bounded arithmetic." Generally, there is a lot of research into what sorts of theorems can be proved in what sorts of axiom systems.

Comment: For what it's worth, Wiles's proof does have an inductive element, albeit not the usual increment-an-integer kind. See part 2 section 5 [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiles%27s_proof_of_Fermat%27s_Last_Theorem#Summary_of_Wiles's_proof), as well as [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiles%27s_proof_of_Fermat%27s_Last_Theorem#General_approach_and_strategy).

Comment: At this stage of mathematical history, our main tool for determining whether induction (or any other method) is a viable proof technique for a certain mathematical problem is: human experience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're question is good. It is a little vague, but these observations form the foundation for asking good, precise questions later. For now, I would motion towards the foundations of mathematics and getting practice with basic proof techniques. In regards to Fermat's last theorem, proof by induction was one of the first things people considered when trying to prove it. I don't know if Fermat's last theorem can or cannot be proven by induction.

I think most practical knowledge about what problems are amenable to what proof techniques comes from experience. Within the categories of direct proof, proof by contradiction, proof by induction, etc., there are patterned ways of solving many kinds of problems. Proofs that require strong induction have a different flavor from proofs that only rely on standard induction. Proofs involving inequalities have a certain thought process associated with them. And, within that, $\varepsilon$-$\delta$ proofs form the backbone of many proofs across mathematics (especially real analysis). Combinatorial proofs are indispensable to prove certain facts in group theory. And so on and so forth. Become familiar with the territory, and the specific question you are investigating will become clear. So, get your hands dirty and solve some problems!